Loop is restarting itself when a correct input is entered
Here is my code.
(Goal) I want to ask a series of questions. The first is asking for a name, if the user inputs the name 'William' I want the program to proceed to ask for their birthdate. If that is answered correctly I want it to ask a series of yes or no questions. If the name 'William' is not entered, I want the program to re-ask for the users name until it is correct so it can proceed.
My issue is that every time I enter the name 'William' it will feed me back this response...
(put below my code)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char correctName[] = "William"; //This is the name that William will need to enter
    char correctBirthday[] = "(01/01/2000)"; //This is the correct birthday he will need to enter

    //The '100' represents how many character can be allowed in each questions answer
    char name[100];
    char birthday[100];
    char response[10];

    while (1) {
        printf("Hello, please enter your name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);

        if (strcmp(name, correctName) == 0) {
            printf("Thank you.\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Searching... \n\nInvalid user. Please enter first and last name.\n\n");
        }
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("I must ask you to confirm your birthdate with me so I can assure that it is you.\n");
        printf("Please do so in this format: (MM/DD/YYYY). \n");
        scanf("%s", birthday);

        if (strcmp(birthday, correctBirthday) != 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Searching... \n\n");
            printf("Invalid input. Only William is authorized to proceed. \n");
        }
    }

    printf("Hello William!\n\n");

    printf("Do you wish to proceed? (yes/no): \n\n");
    scanf("%s", response);

    if (strcmp(response, "yes") == 0) {
        printf("Great! lets get started.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Confirmed, have a nice day.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

//This is what I see when I input 'William'
Hello, please enter your name: William
Searching... 

Invalid user. Please enter first and last name.

Hello, please enter your name: Searching... 

Invalid user. Please enter first and last name.

Hello, please enter your name:

Ive tried rearranging the text and am quite a noob in the coding space right now so I am actively trying to learn as I go. I believe the birthdate text may be backwards but my first priority is to see that text in the first place. Thank you in advance!

Please don't use C++ tag for C questions.

Can't repeat for the name – William is accepted. But not birthday because of a typo: if (strcmp(birthday, correctBirthday) != 0) { break; } has the opposite test from the name input. Function strcmp() returns 0 when the strings are the same. When that is corrected, the program "works" although it is vulnerable to exploits.

I can't reproduce your issue: I copy-pasted the first part of your code, compiled and ran it, enter "William" and got a "Thank you." message (and the loop exited).

I see the prompt asks for two names. If you enter more than one word, %s format will stop at the space, leaving the rest in the input.

@WeatherVane two names? Where?

@9769953 in the code: "Please enter first and last name." If you first enter "David" it refuses and asks for two names, and then it will misfire.

@WeatherVane , ah, the prompt when the initial look-up fails. Since the first prompt just asks for the name (which is better i.m.o. anyway), which is what I saw.

scanf is not suitable for reading strings with spaces because it stops reading at whitespace. This caused the program to only capture the first name when the user entered their full name.
Additionally, the program was breaking out of the loop if the entered birthdate did not match the correct birthdate. However, it should break out of the loop if the birthdates do match so that the program can proceed if the correct birthdate is entered.
I used fgets to read input for the name and birthdate, allowing the program to capture strings with spaces. Also, the logical error in the birthdate comparison was fixed by breaking out of the loop when the correct birthdate is entered.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char correctName[] = "William";
    char correctBirthday[] = "01/01/2000";

    char name[100];
    char birthday[100];
    char response[10];

    while (1) {
        printf("Hello, please enter your name: ");
        fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove the newline character

        if (strcmp(name, correctName) == 0) {
            printf("Thank you.\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Searching...\nInvalid user. Please enter first and last name.\n\n");
        }
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("I must ask you to confirm your birthdate with me so I can assure that it is you.\n");
        printf("Please do so in this format: (MM/DD/YYYY).\n");
        fgets(birthday, sizeof(birthday), stdin);
        birthday[strcspn(birthday, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove the newline character

        if (strcmp(birthday, correctBirthday) == 0) {
            printf("Thank you.\n");
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Searching...\nInvalid input. Only William is authorized to proceed.\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Hello William!\n\n");
    printf("Do you wish to proceed? (yes/no):\n\n");
    fgets(response, sizeof(response), stdin);
    response[strcspn(response, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove the newline character

    if (strcmp(response, "yes") == 0) {
        printf("Great! Let's get started.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Confirmed, have a nice day.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


Thank you, this helped a lot. When I enter the wrong name it will repeatedly ask me until I do so. However when I enter the wrong birthdate it will prompt me to enter it again but when I do, It keeps going down the path as if I didnt enter it correctly. "Not authorized" text. I am wondering how to either be able to enter the correct birthdate and it not give me trouble, or restart to the initial name question.

I don't really understand what you mean. Can you elaborate on your issue
